# xpath select following node of a specific node

Tags: xpath

based on this HTML:

```
< table width='300' ......>
 <tbody>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wcheader1'> ..... </td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wccontnetbox'>......< /td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wccontnetbox'>......< /td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wcheader1'> ..... </td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wccontnetbox'>......< /td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wccontnetbox'>......< /td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wcheader1'> ..... </td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wccontnetbox'>......< /td>
  < /tr>
  < tr>
   < td class = 'wccontnetbox'>......< /td>
  < /tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I have trouble selecting only the first two `<td class='wccontnetbox'>` elements after the first `<td class='wcheader1'>` element. Is there an XPath expression to do this?

**UPDATE**: those elements are dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following expression to select the first two `wccontnetbox` elements after the first `wcheader1`:

```
//table/tbody/tr[td[@class='wcheader1']][2]/
    following-sibling::tr[td[@class='wccontnetbox']][position()<3]/td
```

I'm using `//` because you don't show your full input. It would be better to use a direct path to the table (e.g. `/html/body/<etc>/table...`).

Use the following expression to select all nodes between the first and second `wcheader1` elements:

```
//table/tbody/tr[td[@class='wcheader1']][1]/following-sibling::tr[
    count(.|//table/tbody/tr[td[@class='wcheader1']][2]/preceding-sibling::tr)
     =
    count(//table/tbody/tr[td[@class='wcheader1']][2]/
        preceding-sibling::tr)]/td[@class='wccontnetbox']
```

**Note**: This second expression uses the Kayessian node-set intersection formula. In general, use the following expression to find the intersection of `$set1` and `$set2`:

```
$set1[count(.|$set2)=count($set2)]
```

Comment: @NouNou - Edited answer in response.

Comment: i can't use [position () < 3] because those elements are dynamic .sometimes 4 ,sometimes 6 ....

Comment: @NouNou - What do you mean by dynamic? You asked for the first two `wccontnetbox` elements following the first `wcheader1`, which is what this returns, regardless of overall document position.

Comment: i means the count of these element is dynamic.example :in some web  pages of the website that i want to get data from the count is 5 and some pages the count is 8 and so on .sorry of my bad english.

Comment: is there an expression to select elements between the first <td class='wccontnetbox'> and the second regardless of the count of those elements ?

Comment: @NouNou - Yes, I understand now. I've updated with an expression that selects all nodes between the first and second `wcheader1` elements.